# UIAutomatorViewer - Can't see the option to open UI XML Dump to import ui.uix file

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

I am able to open UIAutomatorviewer from the below location(1).
[image]

unfortunately UI XML Dump option is not in the dialogue box after clicking on open(2)

[image]

Others can see this option when i check in stackover flow forum(3)

[image]

can someone please help me on this!

Comment: Can you insert screenshot instead of giving links? Else, each viewer has to click on three links.

Comment: Sorry, I need 10 reputations to insert images in the post.

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I didn't remember. I did it for you and added an Android tag, for better audience.